# Sybase/HPUX to MSSQL/Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, database-migration

We have a Sybase (15.5) server running on HPUX, and I want to migrate the data to a MSSQL 2017 (CU1) on RHEL 7.3.
I'm trying data export/import via bcp using '-c' (ascii) option.
Everything seems fine except for hebrew characters, a 'א' is originally encoded ascii value 224 (Sybase is using iso_1) but the character is modified to ascii value 133 (MSSQL uses SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CS_AS collation).

Does someone got a clue about this issue ?

Comment: I **assume** your column is a `nvarchar`, not a `varchar`?

Comment: On the Sybase side I have : create table test (z1 nchar(1),nvarchar(1)) then ; insert test select 'א','א'. select ascii(z1),ascii(z2) gives 224,224 values, but after issuing bcp in on sql server I get 63,63

Answer (score 0):

Well, after successfully testing the DirectConnect Odbc drivers it appears that this is a MS drivers limitation.